# .Net smtp not sending emails, no errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, smtp

I am trying to send email through the web application using my client organisation's email server. The following is the code I am using.

```
MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
MyMailMessage.Subject = "Email testing";
MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("name@mydomain.com", "My name");
MyMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(strEmail, "Applicant"));

SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
mySmtpClient.Send(Accepted);
```

Web.config file:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from=" name@mydomain.com">
    <network host="smtps.mydomain.com" port="465" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="true"
    userName="myName" password="myPassword" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

It works perfectly fine when I use gmail smtp details or my local organisation's smtp details. For some reason, its not working and neither is it throwing any errors.

I have tried debugging and checked the exception which says 'timed out'.

I am not sure what else to check. Could someone please suggest a solution.

Note: I have also checked that no firewall is blocking port:465.

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Sud

Comment: I don't understand how this code even compiles; you never declare a variable named `Accepted`.  Perhaps you should change that line to `mySmtpClient.Send(MyMailMessage);`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to test the connection by typing "telnet smtps.mydomain.com 465" in Command Promt(cmd).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var sysLogin="yourlogin@gmail.com";
var sysPass="y0urP@ss";
var sysAddress = new MailAddress(sysLogin, "Message from me!");

var receiverAddress = new MailAddress("mike@hotmail.com");

var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",   //gmail example
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sysLogin, sysPass)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(sysAddress, receiverAddress) { Subject = "Some subject", Body = "Some text" })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the client SMTP server has a valid SSL certificate installed and can accept connections on port 465?

If you are able to do so, run a packet sniffer such as WireShark to check the packet flow.

The SysIntenerals TcpView tool is a lighter-weight utility that would let you see the packet state as well.

Comment: Also checking the log files could determine if you're having DNS sending issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="emialid.com">
        <network host="domain.com" port="25" userName="emialid.com" password="******" defaultCredentials="false"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    </system.net>



public string SendEmailTest(String EmailMessage, String FromMail, String MailPassword, String MailServer, String To, String CC, String BCC, String DisplayName, String Subject, String Attachment)

    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            MailAddress fromAddress;

            fromAddress = new MailAddress(FromMail);

            smtpClient.Host = MailServer;
            smtpClient.Port = 25;

            System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FromMail, MailPassword);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;

            message.From = fromAddress;

            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(To, DisplayName));
            if (CC != "")
                message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(CC, DisplayName));
            if (BCC != "")
                message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(BCC, DisplayName));

            message.Subject = Subject;

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "Your Password is : " + EmailMessage;

            if (Attachment != "")
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Attachment));

            message.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            smtpClient.Send(message);
            return "SendEmail";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Email :" + ex;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I have fixed it, I just had to change the port number from 465 to 25.